# Windows Invalidation after Installing Ubuntu Alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bios

I am having an error on my laptop when I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. Everything was fine, but one month after I installed Ubuntu using the Install Alongside Windows option, I started receiving invalidation errors with Windows 7. The errors says that some of the BIOS license are screwed up, but I haven't touched the BIOS except for changing the boot order. Is it possible that GRUB is messing up the licenses, and if not, what could be causing this issue? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) and Windows 7 Service Pack 1. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hardly think there really is any BIOS issues. I know sometimes Windows can get a little picky if it suddenly sees it's root partition is smaller than it once was. Usually it just does a simple disk check and that's it. But in some cases you might need to reactivate Windows. This usually happens when you make a hardware change, but I've seen some cases where a new dual boot config produces the same thing.

Comment: I try to reactivate Windows, but it keeps saying the key is invalid. And when I look up the Microsoft error code, it says that there are some problems with the BIOS's licenses.